# How do I configure the Artifactory extenstion for Azure Devops using YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory

The documentation describes how to configure the Artifactory extension using the Designder. How do I configure Artifactory Tasks using YAML in An AzureDevops Build Pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Just configure it with the designer and when you are done press "View YAML" button:

[image]

ps. Some extensions have schema published online, some dont